ошибка в uncompyle6: <class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Я пытаюсь декомпилировать программу exe. Использовал uncompyle6 и EasyPythonDecompiler. Везде похожая ошибка:

bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Еще пытался использовать unpy2exe, но при вводе unpy2exe -o ./output_dec ./program.exe получается "unpy2exe" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом..
Вот полная попытка декомпилировать программу:
uncompyle6 pkg_resources._vendor.platformdirs.__main__.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ivan\appdata\local\programs\python\PYTHON~2\Lib\site-packages\xdis\load.py", line 304, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Ill-formed bytecode file pkg_resources._vendor.platformdirs.__main__.pyc
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)

И EasyPythonDecompiler:
Decompiling...
argparse.pyc
Invalid pyc/pyo file - Magic value mismatch!

Decompiling...
ast.pyc
Invalid pyc/pyo file - Magic value mismatch!
...
(И так с каждым .pyc файлом)

Exe распаовывал распаковывал через pyinstxtractor:
 favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
[*] Processing program.exe
[*] Pyinstaller version: 2.1+
[*] Python version: 311
[*] Length of package: 89855023 bytes
[*] Found 4223 files in CArchive
[*] Beginning extraction...please standby
[+] Possible entry point: pyiboot01_bootstrap
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_inspect
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_pyqt5
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_pkgutil
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_multiprocessing
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_traitlets
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_pkgres
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_setuptools
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth__tkinter
[+] Possible entry point: main
[*] Found 2697 files in PYZ archive
[*] Successfully extracted pyinstaller archive: program.exe

You can now use a python decompiler on the pyc files within the extracted directory

Что и на каком шаге я сделал не так?

А версии питонов совпадают? Могу ошибаться, но нужно декомпилировать той же версией питона, что и скомпилировала .pyc файл.

@Amgarak, Версии совпадают, и там и там python 3.9
